# How can you make Moshi handle complex nested data?

Tags: json, moshi

Suppose I've got some JSON data coming in that I ultimately want to represent in code like this:

```
data class Parent(val id: String, val children: List<Child>)

data class Child(val id: String, val parentId: String)
```

But the JSON that comes in is more like this:

```
{
  "id": "parent-1",
  "children": [
    {
      "idPrefix": "child",
      "idNum": "1"
    },
    {
      "idPrefix": "child",
      "idNum": "2"
    },
    {
      "idPrefix": "child",
      "idNum": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

In other words, you need to use custom adapters for:

1. Properly composing `Child.id` when parsing each child.
2. Adding the `child.parentId` to each child when parsing the parent.

It's simple enough to write a `ChildAdapter` that can combine `idPrefix` and `idNum`. But once you get to the second layer of nesting, I'm not sure what to do; I don't want to parse the whole thing as one big blob of data and then work with it all manually. Is there a better way to handle this (potentially nesting even more than 2 levels)?

Additionally, this would hopefully work in both directions - that is, both `fromJson()` as well as `toJson()`.